# systemd NOT directing standard output to a file

Tags: systemd, rhel, stdout

Our service-definition, running under `systemd --user`, begins with:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=append:logs/foo.log
StandardError=fd:stdout
```

The service starts without obvious errors and the actual program runs Ok too. However, nothing appears in the specified log-file and, when I list the files opened by the process (`lsof -p PID`), I see that the file-descriptors 1 and 2 are both *sockets* instead of referring to the file.

I tried specifying absolute path to the log-file too -- it made no difference.

We're on RHEL7, where systemd is of version 219-78 -- is this a known problem, perhaps? Is there a solution/workaround?